# Stop orientation change on page level Windows 8.1 Store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

My Winodws 8.1 store app is supporting all 4 `DisplayOrientations`, except for a one page. When user goto that page I want to restrict the orientation to

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape | DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped;
```

But I don't know where to set it and I tried it on `OnNavigateTo()` it didn't work. Please advice.

Comment: http://wildermuth.com/2013/06/21/Forcing_Orientation_in_WinRT

Comment: Thank you so much, I want the same thing to enforce with or without the accelerometer support. Just like if you enforce it using the package.appxmanifest's supported rotations. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds to me you are trying to solve a non-existing problem.  If the device doesn't have an accelerometer then it also doesn't know when to change the orientation.  So it doesn't happen at all so can't be oriented wrong.